# Python numpy how to reshape this list of arrays/images into a collage?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I've got the following list of 25 mini black-and-white images representing patterns:

`imgs.shape`

`(25, 3, 3, 1)`

I.e. there are 25 different 3x3 black and white image patterns. What I want to do is create a single large image that's `5x5` of these `3x3` blocks, does that make sense? Kind of like this below:

[image]

My intention is then to have something of shape `(15, 15, 1)` that I can display and view like this. I'm using numpy and opencv with Python. I am looking to do something quite efficient for real-time processing, so I thought numpy's reshape might make sense.

Comment: Is it that simple? What order will it collage the images?

Comment: Is `imgs.reshape((15, 15, 1))` not fulfiling your requirement?

Comment: @miradulo can you define row-major vs col-major? So 1 through 5 is first row, then 6 through 11 below it, etc? This is probably what I need. Go ahead and add an answer and I'll test and accept :)

Comment: @JDS There's some useful info in the docs [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#internal-memory-layout-of-an-ndarray). It can be useful to play around with smaller arrays to see how things work. And if someone else wants to write an answer they are welcome to.

Comment: Okay, I never tested them on images - I have to use swapaxes().Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
imgs.reshape(5, 5, 3, 3, 1).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(15, 15, 1)
```

Examples:

```
# test data 
# each 3x3 image consists of the 9 identical digits

A = np.stack([
    np.full((3, 3, 1), i)
    for i in range(1, 26)
])

with_swap = A.reshape(5, 5, 3, 3, 1).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(15, 15, 1)
print(with_swap[...,-1])

without_swap = A.reshape(15, 15, 1)
print(without_swap[...,-1])
```

With swap:

```
[[ 1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3  4  4  4  5  5  5]
 [ 1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3  4  4  4  5  5  5]
 [ 1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3  4  4  4  5  5  5]
 [ 6  6  6  7  7  7  8  8  8  9  9  9 10 10 10]
 [ 6  6  6  7  7  7  8  8  8  9  9  9 10 10 10]
 [ 6  6  6  7  7  7  8  8  8  9  9  9 10 10 10]
 [11 11 11 12 12 12 13 13 13 14 14 14 15 15 15]
 [11 11 11 12 12 12 13 13 13 14 14 14 15 15 15]
 [11 11 11 12 12 12 13 13 13 14 14 14 15 15 15]
 [16 16 16 17 17 17 18 18 18 19 19 19 20 20 20]
 [16 16 16 17 17 17 18 18 18 19 19 19 20 20 20]
 [16 16 16 17 17 17 18 18 18 19 19 19 20 20 20]
 [21 21 21 22 22 22 23 23 23 24 24 24 25 25 25]
 [21 21 21 22 22 22 23 23 23 24 24 24 25 25 25]
 [21 21 21 22 22 22 23 23 23 24 24 24 25 25 25]]
```

Without swap:

```
[[ 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2]
 [ 2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  4  4  4]
 [ 4  4  4  4  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5]
 [ 6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  7  7  7  7  7  7]
 [ 7  7  7  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  9  9  9]
 [ 9  9  9  9  9  9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10]
 [11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 12 12 12 12 12 12]
 [12 12 12 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 14 14 14]
 [14 14 14 14 14 14 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15]
 [16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 17 17 17 17 17 17]
 [17 17 17 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 19 19 19]
 [19 19 19 19 19 19 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20]
 [21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 22 22 22 22 22 22]
 [22 22 22 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 24 24 24]
 [24 24 24 24 24 24 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25]]
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is needed? What happens vs. just doing the reshape(15,15,1) ?

Comment: How about this: `imgs_cols = imgs.reshape(25 * 3, 3, 1)` just gives you a column of images. If you then do `imgs_col.reshape(15, 15, 1)` you are going to get rows that contain about 1.5 images at a time. But we also know that `imgs.reshape(25 * 3, 3, 1).reshape(15,15,1) == imgs.reshape.reshape(15,15,1)`. This is why simple reshaping does not work.

Comment: Yeah the default reshape seems to be giving me messed up results. I'll think through and try your way.

Comment: Yo awesome it worked! Thanks bro. I had a feeling there was more to it than just the simple reshape.