# Transform numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array `Data` of `1D` of size `[36*64]`. Basically, I have `36`, `8*8` images stored in a `1D` array. Each image is stored in `Height(8)*Width(8)` format.

For e.g.: i<sup>th</sup> image is stored from `Data[i*8*8 : (i*8*8 + 8*8)]`.

Now I want to make a tile of images from the given 36 images, i.e. 6 images stacked on top of each other. [Example](https://cipher.dakiscdn.com/i/https://1410dd2bdd37e05ebf19-a2305060cc55ab8db83b1ef4b8835a6b.ssl.cf5.rackcdn.com/900_pgg_9a3a65f0-ca43-0131-46c9-00163e618d24?&w=400&h=400&p=1&a=1&q=render).

Basically, I want to transform my 1D Numpy array into a 2D array of images in the above mentioned format.

I would prefer answers with just using Numpy methods.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50669984/python-numpy-how-to-reshape-this-list-of-arrays-images-into-a-collage/50670160#50670160

Answer (score 0):

To convert  your `1D` array to `2D` use `reshape` as shown with an example:

```
# Creating 36 images each of shape 8x8
initial_1D = np.random.randn(2304).reshape(36, 8, 8)
```

Collage can be formed using `PIL`. For clear understanding refer here [Making a collage in PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438802/making-a-collage-in-pil)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can do it like this

```
# make example data
a = np.linspace(0, 36*64-1, 36*64)
print(a[:64])
print(a.shape)

# reshape 1D to 3D array
b = a.reshape(-1, 8, 8)
# look at first "image"
print(b[0])
```

If I did not understand you correctly, you need to put the -1, 8, 8 in a different order.

Comment: I want the output to be 2D array. ANd in this one image will be stored in multiple rows. So Reshape won't work I guess.

Comment: Like this? `b = a.reshape(8, -1, 8).transpose(0, 2, 1).reshape(64, -1)`